# ByteBuddy 1.10.2 throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resolve type description for java.lang.Exception`, and similar

Tags: mule, byte-buddy, byteman

I am seeing `Cannot resolve type description` errors from `AgentBuilder.Listener.onError(...)` when installing an `AgentBuilder` transformation for an `Instrumentation`.

The agent code is:

```java
  public static void premain(final String agentArgs, final Instrumentation inst) {
    System.out.println("from bytebuddy: agent premain");
    new AgentBuilder.Default(new ByteBuddy().with(TypeValidation.DISABLED))
      .disableClassFormatChanges()
      .ignore(none())
      .with(RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
      .with(InitializationStrategy.NoOp.INSTANCE)
      .with(TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
      .with(new AgentBuilder.Listener() {
        public void onDiscovery(final String typeName, final ClassLoader classLoader, final JavaModule module, final boolean loaded) {
          log("Event::onDiscovery(" + typeName + ", " + getNameId(classLoader) + ", " + module + ", " + loaded + ")");
        }

        public void onTransformation(final TypeDescription typeDescription, final ClassLoader classLoader, final JavaModule module, final boolean loaded, final DynamicType dynamicType) {
          log("Event::onTransformation(" + typeDescription.getName() + ", " + getNameId(classLoader) + ", " + module + ", " + loaded + ", " + dynamicType + ")");
        }

        public void onIgnored(final TypeDescription typeDescription, final ClassLoader classLoader, final JavaModule module, final boolean loaded) {
          log("Event::onIgnored(" + typeDescription.getName() + ", " + getNameId(classLoader) + ", " + module + ", " + loaded + ")");
        }

        public void onError(final String typeName, final ClassLoader classLoader, final JavaModule module, final boolean loaded, final Throwable throwable) {
          log("Event::onError(" + typeName + ", " + getNameId(classLoader) + ", " + module + ", " + loaded + ")", throwable);
        }

        public void onComplete(final String typeName, final ClassLoader classLoader, final JavaModule module, final boolean loaded) {
          log("Event::onComplete(" + typeName + ", " + getNameId(classLoader) + ", " + module + ", " + loaded + ")");
        }
      })
      .type(hasSuperType(named("com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder")))
      .transform(new Transformer() {
        public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(final DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, final     
          System.out.println("from bytebuddy: transform");
          TypeDescription typeDescription, final ClassLoader classLoader, final JavaModule module) {
          return builder.visit(Advice.to(AHCBuilderExit.class).on(isDefaultConstructor()));
        }})
      .installOn(inst);
  }
```

This is using ByteBuddy v1.10.2 with Mule 4 (jdk1.8) as the target application.

There is a similar post regarding this same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535211/byte-buddy-1-9-x-throws-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-resolve-type-de), but the responses have not led me to a solution.

The output shows "from bytebuddy: agent premain", but it does not show "from bytebuddy: transform". Instead, the logs show exceptions for many classes that belong in the bootstrap class loader, such as:

```java
Event::onError(org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguage, org.mule.runtime.module.artifact.api.classloader.MuleArtifactClassLoader@6d4b1d14, null, false)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resolve type description for java.lang.Exception
    at net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Resolution$Illegal.resolve(TypePool.java:159)
    at net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$WithLazyResolution$LazyTypeDescription.delegate(TypePool.java:914)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$AbstractBase$OfSimpleType$WithDelegation.getSuperClass(TypeDescription.java:8031)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfNonGenericType.getSuperClass(TypeDescription.java:3619)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDefinition$SuperClassIterator.next(TypeDefinition.java:314)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDefinition$SuperClassIterator.next(TypeDefinition.java:281)
    at net.bytebuddy.matcher.HasSuperTypeMatcher.matches(HasSuperTypeMatcher.java:53)
...
```

It seems that the class loader that's being queried for the type description is not providing the desired classes. Is there a way to specify an alternate `ClassFileLocator` for these lookups?

The specific class loader that's resulting in the error is:
**`org.mule.runtime.module.artifact.api.classloader.MuleArtifactClassLoader`**

Interestingly, this instrumentation works as expected when using Byteman as the agent, with the following rule file:

```java
RULE AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder.<init>
CLASS com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder
METHOD <init>
AT EXIT
IF TRUE
DO
  traceln("from byteman: AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder.<init> triggered: " + getClass().getClassLoader());
ENDRULE
```

Any advice would be appreciated!
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you share what type the class loader has in the `onError` callback? The `Exception` type should always be resolvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace shows that you are applying a super type check with Byte Buddy that you do not use with Byteman. If you substitute your `hasSuperType(named(...))` matcher with just `named(...)`, it might work without errors as this is where the error seems to happen. Byte Buddy needs to resolve all classes in a class hierarchy for being able to apply this matcher what seems to be impossible in your case.

Yet, that a `ClassLoader` cannot resolve the class file for `java.lang.Exception` seems weird; probably the class loader you are using is a custom implementation that does not delegate to the boot loader.

You can circumvent this by defining a custom `LocationStrategy` in your agent that always queries the boot loader as an alternative option:

```
class BootFallbackLocationStrategy implements AgentBuilder.LocationStrategy {

  @Override
  public ClassFileLocator classFileLocator(ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule module) {
     return new ClassFileLocator.Compound(
       ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.of(classLoader),  
       ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.ofBootLoader())
  }
}
```

As mentioned in my comment, if you can name the type of the class loader that is failing to resolve the class file, I might be able to provide a more detailed answer.

I will add a standard implementation of such a location strategy in a future version of Byte Buddy to make working around this problem easier. The progress is tracked in this ticket: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/794

Comment: Thanks for the response @Rafael. I updated my question to specify for which class loader the error occurs: `org.mule.runtime.module.artifact.api.classloader.MuleArtifactClassLoader`. A colleague has found a working solution [here](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-java/pull/855/files), which is exactly what you describe in the issue you mention.